# How to interpret R output for two-way repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, interpretation

How do I interpret the following output from R for a two-way repeated measures ANOVA

```
Model <- aov(value ~ BWRatio * NumGraBoolean + Error(participant/(BWRatio * NumGraBoolean)))
```

[image]

In particular, what does all these Error terms mean and what does their p-value signify? Please excuse my lack of understanding repeated measures and ANOVA in general, but what do the residuals here represent as well?

Comment: If your data would be in a `data.frame` you could use basically the same call (with the added `data = your.df` argument)  to function `aov.car` from the `afex` package (on CRAN) to obtain a more informative output.

Comment: Baron & Li wrote a nice tutorial on [the use of R for psychology experiments and questionnaires](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~baron/rpsych/rpsych.html) where they discuss the construction and interpretation of the error term in `aov` (§7.9).