# How to interpret overlapping interaction plots?

Tags: anova, interaction, interpretation

I have an interaction plot that seems to be overlapping on top of one another, what does this signify?

[image]

Comment: An adjustable dental chair?

Comment: As can be seen here and in your [other question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50598/442), the interaction is **not significant**. Only a main effect of `BWRatio`. Although I would consider it somewhat bad style to ask two different question on essentially the same. Try to integrate this with your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward interpretation is that at the high and low values of BWRatio the mean of "value" is higher for G than it is for N; whereas in the medium values G and N are virtually identical.

Whether this difference is either material or significant is another question which can't be judged from this plot.

The plot could be improved by adding the actual data to it, perhaps in light grey in the background.  This would give more of an immediate idea of how tightly centred around the means the data are and hence a visual sense of how important the deviation of the two lines from eachother is.